# Does Hilbert space has orthogonal/orthonormal basis?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ a Hilbert space.

**Q1)** Does $H$ has an orthogonal/orthonormal basis ? I know that it's true if $H$ has finite dimension, but what happens in infinite dimension ? Because Gramm-Schmidt is not applicable anymore...

**Q2)** If the answer to my previous question is yes, does it still hold if we suppose $H$ being only an inner space (with infinite dimension) ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116496/basis-in-infinite-dimensional-hilbert-spaces

Comment: @usernegativeoneovertwelve: Your link doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "basis" (it usually has only one meaning but in this context it has another one, which may be confusing)

Answer (score 2):

For Q1: the question is a duplicate as noted in the comments.  See [Every Hilbert space has an orthonomal basis - using Zorn's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218092/every-hilbert-space-has-an-orthonomal-basis-using-zorns-lemma)

For Q2:
if $H$ has a countable dense set, **yes**: apply Gram-Schmidt to that dense set in some order.
If $H$ is not separable, in general **no**.  See my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/201149/442